# How to enable copy / cut paste from VM VDi to the windows XP desktop

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I see that you have answered this question .

But can you please elaborate on how to enable clipboard settings from VM VDI to local desktop.

Example - where to go exactly and stuff

Comment: Could you link to the question you refer to, for context?

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Robocopy instead? You can download an admin resource toolkit to get it on XP. It has multiple copy modes and hopefully, won't do what the old school 'copy' is doing.

An alternate solution would be to grab a utility called [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), which is capable of releasing file locks in most cases. It's quite handy.